# Search behavior in Lucene / Elastic Search with analyzers that add tokens?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have an analyzer that will transform I.B.M. as follows: 1: i.b.m[0, 5] 1: i[0, 1] 2: b[2, 3] 3: m[4, 5] 3: ibm[0, 5]. So I.B.M. gets indexed as i.b.m, i b m, and ibm.

My understanding is that query searches are also analyzed. My question is what is the expected behavior when the search term is I.B.M.? I was expecting Elastic Search to find documents such as I.B.M. and IBM, but it does not find the later. My expectation was that search for I.B.M. would be something equivalent to searching i.b.m OR ibm OR i b m. That is because those tokens are added by the analyzer. If the search term is IBM then both documents are found which means that the analyzer is working as expected at indexing time. But what is the expected behavior at search time for analyzers that add tokens?

Here is the specific call:

POST http://hostl.com:9200/entities/_search?pretty=true HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: kodkods:9200
Content-Length: 218
Expect: 100-continue

```
{
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "I.B.M.",
      "default_field": "contents",
      "default_operator": "and",
      "analyzer": "analyzer_text_english"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your mapping description for the analyzer_text_english analyzer. From what I see you probably just need to change that so all its doing is lowercasing the search query and you should be fine.

Comment: analyzer_text_english :

tokenizer: standard
filter : [standard, stop, asciifolding, word_delimiter, lowercase]

Answer (score 0):

Your analyzer is probably to blame, run curl localhost:9200/entities/_analyze -D "I.B.M", to see what you come up with.

I bet its breaking that up into the separate letters I ,B and M and searching for a document that contains all those letters separately. so that a document like  "I B going M" would match

I suggest you set the [catenate_all setting on your word delimiter to true](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/word-delimiter-tokenfilter/) and that should probably do the trick